# Is it possible to redirect 2 different domain vice versa?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I wonder if it's possible to redirect 2 different domains vice versa. Suppose I have 2 domains such as `www.abc.com` and `www.xyz.com`. Now if any viewer clicks `www.abc.com`, it should redirect them to `www.xyz.com` and when any viewer will click `www.xyz.com`, they will be redirected to `www.abc.com`. Is there any feature or hosting service that can do this? I know redirection can be simply done using PHP `header('Location')` but once I did that, it will be redirected to the location site, there's no way to get the original site. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: How would you envision this happening without ending up in an infinite redirect?

Comment: That's why asked the question if there's any solution or way to do that :)

Comment: But.. why would you design something like that?

Comment: It's not my requirement. My client wants that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when going www.xyz.com we wants to redirect user to www.abc.com and when going to www.abc.com we wants to redirect user to www.xyz.com

By using the sessions, we can do.

```
<?php
//on abc.com
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['abc']) || $_SESSION['abc'] != true ){
    $_SESSION['xyz'] = true;
    header('Location: www.xyz.com');
}
```

now,

```
<?php
//on xyz.com
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['xyz']) || $_SESSION['xyz'] != true ){
    $_SESSION['abc'] = true;
    header('Location: www.abc.com');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would make a strong case not to do this with your client. But... using `.htaccess`, we can set a query string flag with the redirect to prevent an infinite redirect loop.

If the address is for `www.abc.com` we redirect to `www.xyz.com` only if the flag (signaling that we weren't already redirected) doesn't exist

This is untested, but the concept will work.

```
RewriteEngine On
#abc => xyz
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^flag=fromxyz$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  www.xyz.com?flag=fromabc [L,R=301]

#xyz => abc
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xyz.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^flag=fromabc$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  www.abc.com?flag=fromxyz [L,R=301]
```

You can also accomplish the same thing with php - by appending a query string to the redirect and testing for it before the `header()` redirect. Something like:

```
if ($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] == "www.abc.com"){
    if ($_SERVER[QUERY_STRING] !== "flag=fromxyz"){
        header("Location: www.xyz.com?flag=fromabc.com"); 
        die();
    }
}
if ($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] == "www.xyz.com"){
    if ($_SERVER[QUERY_STRING] !== "flag=fromabc"){
        header("Location: www.abc.com?flag=fromxyz.com"); 
        die();
    }
}
```

The `.htaccess` method will be more efficient as the server won't have to load a php file before redirecting.

Also, the use of `$_SESSION` variables is an option as mentioned by @AnimeshSahu. However, they may not be supported in all cases (e.g. Googlebot)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the referer

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*abc.com.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  www.xyz.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Says if the referer is not ABC.com then redirect.

Not tested but should work as the 301 will include the referer